# Me gustaria modificar o actualizar los datos usando el metodo PUT y la clase CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estoy buscando un metodo que pueda modificar el codigo usando el metodo **PUT** para llamar al servicio y la clase **CrudRepository** para decir lo que quiero.
¿Sabéis como puedo modificar?
***Este es un pequeño ejemplo usando con save:***
la variable people, llama a la **interface** de la clase **CrudRepository**

```
  public String save(Personas person) {
   String mensaje = "";
   try {
       people.save(person);
             mensaje = "Se guardo correctamente";


        } catch(Exception exception) {

         mensaje = "Intente de nuevo";
        }
        return mensaje;
    }
```

Aquí llamamos en el controlador

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/persona", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
           @ResponseBody
           public String save(@RequestBody Personas person) {

            return serverPost.save(person);

           }
```

Comment: RequestMethod.PUT, la clase CrudRepository si el objeto lleva un id diferente de cero intentara hacer un update

Comment: Es decir es el mismo metoda save, solo que tienes que enviarle tu llave primara y si esta es null o cero creara un registro y si es diferente de cero hara un update